# Regular expressions to segregate between good words and bad ones

Tags: regex, bash

I have a blacklist of bad words that are blocked if they are used on any web search engine. Examples of those words are: anal, ass, bum bra, butt, cum, dick, lust, tit. 
Normal words that contain any of these previous words as part of their structures are accordingly blocked. Examples of those good words are: analog, canal, analysis, asset, compass, album, brand, button, circumstance, dickson, illustrate, repetition.
My question: is there a regular expression (or bash shell script) that enables me to use the normal words without being blocked because of their blacklisted parts?
Appreciating your interest to help. Thank you.

Comment: Consider using boundries in your black list regexes, for example `/\blust\b/`

Comment: Thanks a lot fardjad, for sure I will apply it now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `\b`, which means "word boundary":

```
\bbutt\b
```

would match `butt` but not `button`.

Comment: Yes, for sure this is a simple and practical solution, never thought about it. Many thanks.

Comment: I actually applied your solution, but it seems not working on squidGuard. I believe your and Fardjad's suggested solution "word boundary" is ideal, but its application may necessitate another way to work on squidGuard; any suggestions?

Comment: after extensive testing, I found out that squidGuard doesn't accept a bunch of regex operators/directives such as: \b, \w, \< and considers them as "normal text". So any string with such directives as prefixes or suffixes become part of the string, hence if I want to block butt through \bbutt\b expression, butt will pass, and \bbutt\b will be blocked, that is really "amazing". Accordingly, I think a bash shell script could be a solution unless someone could think, or has the knowledge, of how to make squidGuard "wake up" for regex operators. Any suggestions?

Comment: @JosefMiller I'm sorry, I don't really know squidGuard, but I think this would make for a very good question on SO (about how to make `\b`  work in squidGuard)